How to use MUI DatePicker component in React-Hook-Form?
I want to use a MUI DatePicker component in React-Hook-Form. However, when I select a date, there is an error.
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <Demo />
    </LocalizationProvider>
)

import {Controller, useForm} from "react-hook-form";

export const Demo = () => {
    const {control} = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            dateOfBirth: null,
        }
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <Controller
                name="dateOfBirth"
                control={control}
                render={({field: {onChange}}) => (
                    <DatePicker
                        label="Date of Birth"
                        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                        onChange={date => onChange(dayjs(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </form>
    )
}

enter image description here
I use <Controller/> from react-hook-form to control the MUI DatePicker and the control prop of DatePicker has been assigned the control value destructured from useForm() hook from react-hook-form. I don't understand why the error exists. Would someone please help?

Updated code: try to below code
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { LocalizationProvider, DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const Demo = () => {
    const { control } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            dateOfBirth: dayjs().toDate(),
        },
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <Controller
                name="dateOfBirth"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...restField } }) => (
                    <DatePicker
                        {...restField}
                        label="Date of Birth"
                        value={value || null}
                        onChange={(newDateValue) => {
                            onChange(dayjs(newDateValue).toDate());
                        }}
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </form>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <Demo />
    </LocalizationProvider>
);


Thanks for your reply. I've tried your codes but there is a warning stating "The renderInput prop has been removed in version 6.0 of the Date and Time Pickers.". I updated my codes and when I console log the value of dateOfBirth, it shows "2024-06-09", it's a string. I've tried to add rules={{valueAsDate: true}} to  but it doesn't work. How can I convert the date value from string to date? @Kishan Dobariya

PLease make onchage funcation like handleDateChange

inside, set the setValue('dateOfBirth', Dayjs(newDate));

This is a convert the string to a Dayjs object before setting the value

I still can't get it. Would you please provide a codesandbox showing the working codes? @Kishan Dobariya

check the : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78594797/20821401

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { LocalizationProvider, DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const Demo = () => {
    const { control } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            dateOfBirth: dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), // Set a default value if needed
        },
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <Controller
                name="dateOfBirth"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <DatePicker
                        {...field}
                        label="Date of Birth"
                        value={field.value || null} // Ensure value is not undefined
                        onChange={(date) => field.onChange(dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
                        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    />
                )}
            />
        </form>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <Demo />
    </LocalizationProvider>
);


DatePicker Props: value={field.value || null}: Ensure DatePicker always receives a value (even if null initially). onChange={(date)
=> field.onChange(dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}: Ensure DatePicker's onChange updates the form state with the formatted date
string.
defaultValues:  This ensures the dateOfBirth field is initialized with a valid value.


Thanks for your reply. l updated my codes based on your codes and find that the value prop of DatePicker isn't required if a default value is added to useForm() hook. However, I find another problem. When I console log the value of dateOfBirth, it shows "2024-06-09", it's a string. I've tried to add rules={{valueAsDate: true}} to  but it doesn't work. How can I convert the date value from string to date? @Khushbu Patel

Please set the default value :- dateOfBirth: dayjs().toDate(). also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/78594797/20821401
